# solving django 1.10 integrity error

Tags: python, django

I created two models **`Category`** and **`Song`**. I linked `Song` to `Category` using *foreign key* and then I linked `Song` to `User` using *foreign key*. I then created created a form to add song to the database, but anytime I use the form I get this error

```
Integrity Error  NOT NULL constraint failed: home_song.user_id (home is the name of the app)"
```

How do I solve this error?

My models:

```
class Category(models.Model):  
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)  

class Song(models.Model):  
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Comment: please show your forms and views.

Answer (score 2):

However you're creating Song objects, you're not giving it an associated User to store in that field.

If having a user is not necessary, you need to modify the User field to allow null values.

`user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: having a user is neccessary , i kind of want to know wat user uploaded a certain song

Comment: Ok, so how are you collecting the input? You're not storing any user information to the object when you try to save it, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: In the website u need to log in to upload songs . so wen u logged in and want to upload a song django will automatically get d user

Comment: Yes, good, so in any given view request.user will have the user object, now you need to store that to song.user wherever you create the song object, then save it.

Comment: How do I do that